Red Hat Dependency Analytics Command failed
I wanted to see dependency analytics report of my maven project, but it said 'Unable to analyze your stack.' and an error message popped up as follows.
Command failed: mvn -q clean -f /my-project/pom.xml

Source: Red Hat Dependency Analytics

I also added Red Hat's generally available (GA) repository to my pom.xml as written in extension details as follows.
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>redhat-ga</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

What shall I do?
